# What settings do I input for syncing another Outlook account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to see emails from 2@outlook.com in 1@outlook.com; I'll compose and answer emails from 2@outlook.com in 2, not 1.  Screenshot below proves that I synced my 3@aol.com successfully. All messages from it appear in my 1@outlook.com with a yellow bar

[image]

My username and password for 2@outlook.com are correct. What else do I have to do?

[image]

Comment: You appear to be missing the IMAP and SMTP server details.

Comment: Why are you setting up this account manually for IMAP and not allowing Outlook to add it as an Exchange account automatically?  If Outlook/Hotmail accounts even allow what you're trying to do with IMAP _(syncing one account into a directory within the other account)_, it's going to create more problems than it solves, unless you manually configure Email2 to only sync specific folders _(such as Inbox only)_ in the Send/Receive... settiungs.

Comment: @JW0914 "not allowing Outlook to add it as an Exchange account automatically" I don't want to add this account to my MS Outlook. I only desire to see emails in it on 1@outlook.com.

Comment: @Ghreu Are you using OWA or Outlook?  If the latter, you're still adding this account to Outlook and it will still have an `ost` database.  As I mentioned previously, I don't believe hotmail/outlook accounts allow syncing one account into the directory of another hotmail/outlook account.

Comment: @JW0914 Outlook software on desktop, not OWA.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put anything in the incoming IMAP server field. However you don’t need to go through all that to accomplish your task. Just follow these steps:

1. In Outlook Web App, click Settings > Options > Organize Email >
   Inbox Rules.
2. On the Inbox rules tab, click the arrow next to the
   plus symbol +, and select Create a new rule for arriving messages.
3. Under When the message arrives, select Apply to all messages.
4. Under Do the following, select Redirect the message to.
5. Select the address you want your mail sent to by double-clicking it in the
   address book view. If the address you want to redirect to isn’t in
   the address book, you can enter the email address in the To line at
   the top of the window.
6. Click OK to save your selections and return to the new rule window.
7. Click Save to save your rule and
   return to the Inbox rules tab

.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not hearing what you want, everyone is offering alternatives to what you want rather than answering you directly.

So, if you want to connect to outlook.com there is more information you need to fill in.

You see the line that says "Incoming (IMAP) Server *"? The * indicates that you must provide information here.

In your case, you want to enter "imap-mail.outlook.com".

The line below that, "Incoming Server Port" should remain as it is "993"

Below that is "encryption" if there is an option to select "SSL/TLS' then do so, if not then leave it as it is with "SSL"

Now go down to the line that says "Outgoing (SMTP) Server *" Here you want to enter "smtp-mail.outlook.com"

The port "587" is correct.

If there is any mention of encryption below this select "STARTTLS"

That should make it work for you. Good luck.